# How to make Laravel 8 sessions work on Heroku? Since they are not saved correctly

Tags: php, laravel, session, heroku, redis

I have an application with Laravel 8 that saves a value in a session variable.

```
Route::post('login', function (Request $request) {

$matchThese = ['user' => $request->user, 'password' => $request->password];


if (User::where($matchThese)->count() > 0) {

    session(['user' => $request->user]);

    return "Bienvenido " . session('user');

 }else{

    return "Datos incorrectos";

 }});
```

Then I try to get it but I get nothing.

```
Route::get('get', function () {

return session('user');});
```

I am using redis to connect it with Heroku.

```
    'redis' => [

    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST'),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],

if (getenv('REDIS_URL')) {
$url2 = parse_url(getenv('REDIS_URL'));

putenv('REDIS_HOST='.$url2['host']);
putenv('REDIS_PORT='.$url2['port']);
putenv('REDIS_PASSWORD='.$url2['pass']);}
```

Any help on how to use laravel 8 sessions on Heroku?

Comment: How do you know that this is a Heroku issue? Does your code work in your local instance?

Comment: yes it works but not on heroku